# Redirecting to sign in when doing `post` in functional test even when signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, factory-bot, functional-testing

I'm writing out some functional tests for a rails app that uses devise for authentication. Everything works great except when it comes down to tests that create.

My `ActionController::TestCase` is setup the following way...

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  setup do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = User.where(email: FactoryGirl.build(:functional_user).email).first
  end

  def login_user
    sign_in @user
  end

end
```

My test case looks like...

```
  test "should not create property (logged in)" do
    login_user
    assert_no_difference('Property.count') do
      post :create, @property
    end

    assert_redirected_to new_property_path(@property)
  end
```

The result is a fail.

> test_should_not_create_property_(logged_in)(PropertiesControllerTest)
>   [/home/vagrant/projects/outdoors/test/functional/properties_controller_test.rb:39]:Expected
>   response to be a redirect to <"http://test.host/properties/new"> but
>   was a redirect to <"http://test.host/users/sign_in">

The same goes if I am trying to create a property and assert a difference the property is not created.

The logging in of the user seems to work fine in other cases like

```
  test "should get new properties page (not logged in)" do
    get :new
    assert_redirected_to user_session_path
  end

  test "should get new properties page (logged in)" do
    login_user
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Note: Unit tests and tests in the browser are working fine.

Any clue to what is going on?

Comment: I don't know where the problem is, but do you really want a list containing a hash for the argument of `picture_attributes`?

Comment: Now that I study it, the result is consistent with a validation failing and consequent redirect to the sign in page. Carefully inspect logs to make progress.

Comment: new_property_path(@property) redirects to http://test.host/properties/new. Use rake routes | grep sign_in in your console to get the sign_in path.

Comment: @Emu I don't want it to go to sign_in. Its behaving as if there isn't a user signed in.

Comment: @Gene any suggestions on getting better logs. What I posted above is the most I guest even with TESTOPS="-v". There is no log file?

Comment: @Adgezaza I mean the Rails log in log/test.log.  See for example http://robots.thoughtbot.com/tail-your-test-logs